# how to enable GPS forcibly in android 4.0 or higher

Tags: java, android, gps, android-sensors

open `GPS` programmaticlly can be easy in early version,but in `4.0 - 4.4`,it may be banned by google.how can I solve it?

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare so,how can I retrieve GPS every minute in background with just one request for user?

Comment: If the user has GPS enabled, you do not need any "request for user" -- just use `LocationManager` or `LocationClient`. If the user chooses to enabled GPS briefly for one of your checks, then disables it again, so you wind up prompting the user again, that is the user's choice to make. Most likely, in this case, the user will simply choose to uninstall your app.